# Which user-agent are the glass using?

Tags: google-mirror-api

We are posting videos against the mirror api but the overall quality of the videos are not that great.
We think that this may be related to the user-agent the glass are using to make the request for the video and this influences the video served.
Anyone knows which user-agent the glass are using to make requests?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

The built in browser says:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-us; Glass 1 Build/IMM76L; XE9) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

I'm not sure whether the same user-agent is used for REST calls.